# Out of memory Exception in android : app re-allocates memory for screens used in past

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

My app has been crashing a lot because of out of memory exceptions.

I opened the memory tool and noticed that memory allocation kept increasing as I went back and forth between only 2 activities:

Suppose I have a Timeline of 'Sessions' (a list view), tapping a session takes me to the session activity.

Here is what happens when I go from Timeline to session 1, then press Back to return to the timeline, then go to session 1 again :

[image: memory allocation graph]

I've looked at Android's documentation for Displaying bitmaps (https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) but it doesn't address my issue

It seems that the issue is that it's reallocating memory for activities that I've already visited, Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: this is clearly a memory leak. always recycle bitmap when not used to prevent leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing memory leak problem. I recommend you use [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect which cause this leak. As it's document you can initialize it in you `Application` like:

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```

Then use it in your `Activity`:

```
@Override public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = ExampleApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
    refWatcher.watch(this);
  }
```